# Where is libmysqlclient.16.dylib

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I've been following advice from StackOverflow posts and I've been asked for MySQLdb  to verify that I have  `libmysqlclient.16.dylib` on my compute. Where do I find this in OS X 10.8?

Comment: Try "find / -iname libmysqlclient.16.dylib" in a Terminal and be patient. Did you install MySQL yourself, or do you use MacPorts or homebrew?

Comment: Another option, run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` then, after that command completes run `locate libmysqlclient*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo find / -iname libmysqlclient.*`